# Super Fast File Storage Engine

Tags: java, performance, postgresql, concurrency, database-performance

I basically have one big gigantic table (about 1.000.000.000.000 records) in a database with these fields:

id, block_id, record

id is unique, block_id is not unique, it contains about 10k (max) records with the same block_id but with different records

To simplify my job that deals with the DB I have an API similar to this:

```
Engine e = new Engine(...);
// this method must be thread safe but with fine grained locked (block_id) to improve concurrency
e.add(block_id, "asdf"); // asdf up to 1 Kilobyte  max

// this must concatenate all the already added records added block_id, and won't need to be bigger than 10Mb (worst case) average will be <5Mb
String s = e.getConcatenatedRecords(block_id);
```

If I map each block to a file(haven't done it yet), then each record will be a line in the file and I will still be able to use that API

But I want to know if I will have any peformance gain by using flat files compared to a well tunned postgresql database ? (at least for this specific scenario)

My biggest requirement though is that the getConcatenatedRecords method returns stupidly fast (not so with the add operation). I am considering caching and memory mapping also, I just don't want to complicate myself before asking if there is an already made solution for this kind of scenario ?

Comment: "already made solution for this kind of scenario".  Maybe S3?  :-)

Comment: postgres already uses caching so if you tend to always call the same blocks it should not have to access the disk too much. Can you precalculate the string concatenation and store it in a separate table when a new record is added?

Comment: @assylias, postgres is already manging this thing very fast, but as this thing grows, I want to look for alternatives.

Comment: @Gray, this thing is to have a file that will be appended over time (concurrent writes must be sincronized). There will be many many different files. And over time reads to those files should be fast. I just want to know if plan text files will be the best or I can use another approach. Will S3 serve this scenario?

Comment: I was being a bit facetious @DavidHofmann.  I suspect you are going to have to be running this on a seriously large bit of hardware to make it scale to 1T rows and still be performant.

Comment: well, i don't need to have everything in the same machine. I already have postgres databases in 3 boxes (and I have very little load to date). I only care that equal block_id's stay in the same box. For the rest I can spread the load with no problem. I just want to know if I can do better with another storage engine given the simple scenario that I have.

Comment: This sounds like a classic case of the [inner platform effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect). You appear to be trying to build a filesystem on top of a database, on top of a filesystem.  If you want a remote file system protocol, why not use a remote file system protocol, not PostgreSQL? If you want an object store, why not use an object store, like OpenStack's Swift (http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/) ? (The exception is when you need to sync file updates into transactions with other PostgreSQL changes; in that case, expect to pay the performance price).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research. I found that these data stores makes for the most part of use cases I have:

- [MVStore of H2 Database](http://h2database.com/html/mvstore.html)
- [MapDB](http://www.mapdb.org/)
- [Oracle Bekeley DB Java Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index-093405.html)
- And Kyoto Cabinet that seems to have inactive development

The interesting part is that all they mostly back the API of java collections (lists, sets, maps...)

EDIT: All these Proyects allows me to open a file as a data store of huge collections and I can reference them by name, and there can be many collections per file. Each of them are indexed. The idea is that these proyects are to be used as a foundation for real databases, you can view them as the data store engine of the database (be it SQL or NoSQL). Because these proyects are the foundation for proyects like mongodb, h2database and orientdb, then I am sure that if the simplistic datasotre approach fits my needs, it will also scale without any problems. Because my partition needs are very simplistic I can also share the load with other nodes.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you already have this running in postgres - can you post the schema you're using? It's certainly *possible* to do better than a well-tuned database in very specific scenarios, but usually turns out to be vastly more work than you imagine going in (especially if you're synchronizing writes).

Are you using [CLUSTER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-cluster.html) with your index? What are the storage settings for the table?

And how large can the table get before your queries become too slow?

Comment: just 1 table :) just those 3 columns :D and just default settings... I am sorry

Comment: I was thinking on having everything compresed in RAM. and have that in sync with the DB so I can rebuild it if the system crashes. After all, writes will be easily synced, disk flush is not that importat that it occurs immediatelly but reads must be fast!

Comment: well, actually to have in RAM only the live part of the data, it will be impossible to have everything...

Comment: I haven't done any test about when it comes slow, up to what I am using now it's just pretty dam fast

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be building an object store on top of PostgreSQL, why not use an object store instead?

I'd start with OpenStack Swift:

- [OpenStack Block Storage (Swift)](http://www.openstack.org/software/openstack-storage/)
- [Swift docs](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/)

or, alternately, a *distributed network file system*, if that's closer to your needs. (ab)using PostgreSQL as a network file system isn't going to get you far if you care about performance. The only time I'd do that would be when I needed ACID semantics - such as atomic commits of some database changes along with a file they relate to.

You don't get atomic commit over multiple PostgreSQL instances (though you get close, with prepared tranactions) so I'm guessing that's not your use case. If it isn't, I suggest looking for the right too for the right job.